# DI with auto-generated web service clients

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm trying to do dependency injection throughout the app tier and am running into a scenario I'm sure others have seen.  There are some 3rd party web services that we consume and the clients were auto-generated with a base class.  The clients do not have an interface and the data types are in the same file/project.

The obvious problem is if I want to do unit testing I'll need to mock the service.  I'll need to extract an interface and move the data types into a "contracts" project that is available to both real/mock clients.  However, the next time the client is auto-generated that work needs to be redone.  Creating a proxy at runtime wouldn't help much because then we would have to manually create the interfaces and data types from the WSDL.  Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Would shims via Microsoft Fakes be of use to you in this scenario?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: @BrendanGreen - +1 for something new I learned today.  This could probably work, but since I have control over the client code I would like to avoid going this route if possible.  Definitely a good tool to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extracting an interface from the implementation is not going to help you much anyway, as it's going to be a poor abstraction.

Interfaces should be defined and owned by the clients that consume the interfaces. As [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices](http://amzn.to/19W4JHk) explain, **"clients […] own the abstract interfaces"** (chapter 11). Thus, any attempt to define a data-centric interface like extracting interfaces from auto-generated web service clients is bound to cause problems sooner or later, because it's violating various SOLID principles like the Dependency Inversion Principle or the Interface Segregation Principle.

Instead, your *client code* should define the interfaces that they require. Then you can always *implement* those interfaces with the auto-generated web service clients. If you've used Microsoft's tooling (Visual Studio, wsdl.exe, etc.) the relevant auto-generated class should already be a **partial class**, which means you should be able to add behaviour to it without touching the auto-generated part of it.

Comment: Trying to understand... why would extracting an interface violate the DI principle?  The rest of the code would just reference the interface and the instance could be provided by an IoC container.  Interface segregation I understand since extracting an interface will likely result in unneeded members, but it could be used as as starting point and clean it up if you're likely to use most/all of what the service provides.

Comment: Regarding the client owning the interface and the partial class, are you saying that I should add business logic in a partial class to map from the interface to what the service actually provides?  That's an interesting concept so that the code that depends on the interface doesn't necessarily need to change when the service changes, but if it gets complex enough I would like to test that business logic and I'm right back where I started.

Comment: The DIP says that "Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions." If the interface is defined in the same package as the service, then the client depends on the service package (an implementation detail). That's why the DIP states that clients should own the interfaces they need. And yes, you would probably need to test the conversion logic, but that's not business logic, that's part of the implementation detail. The business logic should be the independent package(s): http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/03/layers-onions-ports-adapters-its-all-the-same

Comment: Right, the interface would go in a separate contracts package/project.  Chapter 11 that you referenced also mentions that a few paragraphs down.  It also says "clients *tend to* own the abstract interfaces and that their servers derive from them."  However, in this case the service is already defined and there aren't likely to be multiple services that implement this interface, though I see your point on the conversion logic.  Anyway, this is all good info and gives me a better idea which way to go.

Comment: Lovely, I just saw you're the creator of AutoFixture which was next on my list of things to prototype.  :)