# Dependency Injection Where Does My Interface Go?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am new to DI containers and have been doing some reading and I was wondering if you guys could help me out with my first sample project.

I have a MVC5 application separated into `n` tier modules. I have my presentation module injecting an `IDataAdapter` into a controller via a `defaultcontrollerfactory.` This `dataadapter` is then passed via constructor injection into a service class that talks to the data access layer via the `IDataAdapter.`

My question is, where is the `IDataAdapter` interface class supposed to be located, obvious the concrete class that implements this interface needs to be in the data access layer. I could leave the interface in the DAL, but then I would need a hard reference between my view and dal, and that does not seem right.

So I made a separate project library to hold my container logic and data adapters, but now I am running into a circular dependency, where my `DataAdapter` needs to implement the `IDataAdapter` interface, but my unity registration file does not know what the `DataAdapter` concrete class is because it can’t reference the DAL.

Comment: As Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices explain in chapter 11, **"clients […] own the abstract interfaces"**. http://amzn.to/19W4JHk

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612/126014

Comment: The short answer is that the client should define *the interface it needs*, which is almost certainly *not* something like `IDataAdapter`, which sounds like a **Leaky Abstraction**. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22164792/126014 for a related discussion.

Answer (score 0):

While using dependency Injection, It would be good to have all interfaces in a separate assembly so that you can avoid any kind of circular dependency.

High level diagram of recommended solution structure:

[image: Click here to see high level diagram of recommended solution structure]

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with sites when you link to them. For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion